# Parsing JSON in a Spark column

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON in a dataframe column that is of type String, and I want to convert that to a map. The catch here is that I don't exactly know the schema of the JSON, since the key name can vary.

Basically, my JSON column looks like:

```
{"outerkey":{"innerkey_1":[{"uid":"1","price":0.01,"type":"STAT"}],
"innerkey_2":[{"uid":"1","price":4.3,"type":"DYN"}],
"innerkey_3":[{"uid":"1","price":2.0,"type":"DYN"}]}}
```

I want this to eventually look like:

```
{"outerkey":
[{"keyname":"innerkey_1","uid":"1","price":0.01,"type":"STAT"}, 
{"keyname":"innerkey_2","uid":"1","price":4.3,"type":"DYN"}, 
{"keyname":"innerkey_3","uid":"1","price":2.0,"type":"DYN"}]}
```

so that I can calculate mean of all prices when type="DYN".

In other words, reading the JSON data using this:

```
val testJsonData = spark.read.json("file:///data/json_example")
```

gives me the following schema:

```
root
 |-- outerkey: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- innerkey_1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- innerkey_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- innerkey_3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
```

However, I'd like to end up with the much simpler:

```
root
 |-- outerkey: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- keyname: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
```

What transformation can I use on the data to be able to end up with the above schema?

Please let me know the easiest way to do this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: show us what you have tried so far and what problem you have faced...

Comment: Well, as I have mentioned, I don't know the schema, so I am unable to read the json in the first place. I guess I could "try" something if I figured that out.

(Letting Spark infer the schema isn't an option here)

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is a bit complex and if my edit of your question is correct then following can be your solution.

you already have input `dataframe` with `schema` as

```
root
 |-- outerkey: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- innerkey_1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- innerkey_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- innerkey_3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
```

The following step would change the `dataframe` to have each `array` in different columns

```
val tempT = testJsonData.select($"outerkey.*")
```

whose `schema` would be

```
root
 |-- innerkey_1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- innerkey_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- innerkey_3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
```

Since you want the keynames in each `struct`s, you need to get the names

```
val schema = tempT.schema.fieldNames
```

Thus schema would be `innerkey_1, innerkey_2, innerkey_3`

Complex part is to add the keynames inside `struct` columns which would require two `for` loops

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
for(column <- schema){
  tt = tt.withColumn(column, explode($"${column}"))
}

for(column <- schema){
  tt = tt.withColumn(column, struct(lit(column).as("keyname"), $"${column}.*"))
}
```

finally `tt` would have keynames added in the `struct` columns as

```
root
 |-- innerkey_1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- keyname: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- innerkey_2: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- keyname: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- innerkey_3: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- keyname: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
```

Final step would be combine all of them into one `column`, opposite of what we did in the first step

```
val temp = tt.select(array(schema.map(col): _*).as("outerkey"))
```

`temp`'s `schema` would be your required `schema`

```
root
 |-- outerkey: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- keyname: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
```

and `temp.toJSON.foreach(x => println(x.toString))` should give you your desired `json` data

```
{"outerkey":[{"keyname":"innerkey_1","price":0.01,"type":"STAT","uid":"1"},{"keyname":"innerkey_2","price":4.3,"type":"DYN","uid":"1"},{"keyname":"innerkey_3","price":2.0,"type":"DYN","uid":"1"}]}
```

Comment: That almost works.

Is this how I'd get the sum of all prices whenever type=="DYN"?
temp.select(explode($"outerkey")).filter($"col.bt"==="DYN").select(sum($"col.price"))

Comment: Yes, @PramodKumar, You got it right. thats the correct way of getting sum of all prices whenever type == "DYN" but its `col.type` **not** `col.bt` in `filter`. `temp.select(explode($"outerkey")).filter($"col.type"==="DYN").select(sum($"col.price")).show(false)`